# P tag does not get updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to create a high score that is saved in localstorage. The application is a quizz application that saves and shows the top 5 score at the end of it (wether it is completed or not).The problem here is that the p tags that I create in the in html file do not get updated by the values in the high score list that I create in the js file. here is the code:

```
<div id = "EndSection">
<h3>The Game is Over. Top 5 Players are:</h3>
<div class = "Player">
<p id = "Player1">xoxo</p>
<p id = "Score1">30</p>
</div>
```

and then i just copy the div class player with the 2 p-tags until I have 5 players.

The javascript code:

```
< function SaveToDataBase (){

//Checks if they completed the quizz, and check if there time is
//enough to be top5, if its enough, then it will run newEntry
var boolean = false;
var Trigger = "score";

HighScoreList.forEach(function(entry){

  if(entry.hasOwnProperty(Trigger)){
    var value = entry[Trigger];
    /*you look in your scores, and his total time is less than theres,  then he is
    added to the list*/
    if(thetotaltimer < value){
      boolean = true;
    }
  }
});
if(boolean){
  newEntry();
}


}


function newEntry(){
//inserts on index
HighScoreList.splice(5, 0, {name: currentPlayer, score: thetotaltimer });

//sort scores
HighScoreList.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.score - b.score;
});
//starts at index 5, then takes away the index right after it (number 6).
HighScoreList.splice(5,1);
localStorage.setItem("SavedHighListObjectz", JSON.stringify(HighScoreList));

document.getElementById("Player1").innerText = JSON.parse(HighScoreList[0].name);
document.getElementById("Score1").innerText = JSON.parse(HighScoreList[0].score);
document.getElementById("Player2").innerText = JSON.parse(HighScoreList[1].name);
document.getElementById("Score2").innerText = JSON.parse(HighScoreList[1].score);
document.getElementById("Player3").innerText = JSON.parse(HighScoreList[2].name);
document.getElementById("Score3").innerText = JSON.parse(HighScoreList[2].score);
document.getElementById("Player4").innerText = JSON.parse(HighScoreList[3].name);
document.getElementById("Score4").innerText = JSON.parse(HighScoreList[3].score);
document.getElementById("Player5").innerText = JSON.parse(HighScoreList[4].name);
document.getElementById("Score5").innerText = JSON.parse(HighScoreList[4].score);
}

function init(){

//this if-statement runs if there is no highscore list already saved
if(localStorage.getItem("SavedHighListObjectz") == undefined) {
HighScoreList = [
  {'name': "Sam", 'score': 300000},
  {'name': "Markus", 'score': 554000},
  {'name': "Cody", 'score': 2210000},
  {'name': "David", 'score': 39000000},
  {'name': "Jackson", 'score': 55500000}
];
localStorage.setItem("SavedHighList", JSON.stringify(HighScoreList));

}else{
//or else we load this
HighScoreList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("SavedHighListObjectz"))
   }
  }
 init();
 questions();>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post it in jsFiddle? 
I think your problem is the space in attritube its should look like this: `id="EndSection"` instand of: `id = "EndSection"`

Comment: Start by removing all that parse code. It is a javaScript object so no need to parse it. Then click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: I'd probably aim to avoid naming variables "boolean", too. Amongst other reasons, it doesn't describe what it is doing.

Comment: I think you have some serious debugging to do Markus. I placed your code into a fiddle and none of it is being called by default. I placed 2 console.log calls, neither shows up. You need to get this working at least a little bit: https://jsfiddle.net/hvrm2vkn/

Answer (score 0):

Various small problems are stopping your code from working:

1.
Your names and scores are just strings - trying to JSON.parse them should result in an "unexpected token" exception.  Are you not seeing that?  Make sure you are able to see javascript exceptions (in Chrome, press F12 and click "console")

2.
localStorage.setItem("SavedHighList" should be localStorage.setItem("SavedHighListObjectz".   To avoid mistakes like this, save your key as a variable:

```
var storageKey="SavedHighListObjectz";
...
localStorage.getItem(storageKey)
...
```

3.
You've only got p tags for one player?  This may be obvious, but (after you've fixed #1 and #2) your example code will bomb at `document.getElementById("Player2").innerText` until you add the html for the other 4 top scores

Comment: After JavaScript automatic type conversion,  `null == undefined` is true. A test using strict equality removes all doubt: `if(localStorage.getItem("SavedHighListObjectz") === null)`

Comment: Thanks @Traktor53 you are right - have removed that bullet point